# mvc3 EditorFor/DisplayFor throws Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We have a MVC3 website works fine in development box, but after put into production, it throws the exception "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute." quite often. And the exceptions are from multiple pages. The only common patter I found so far is: all the pages call a partial view, and the partial view either use EditorFor or DisplayFor, that's where the exception throws. Here is one stack trace:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<ConcatIterator>d__71`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngineCollection.Find(Func`2 lookup, Boolean trackSearchedPaths)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.ExecuteTemplate(HtmlHelper html, ViewDataDictionary viewData, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, GetViewNamesDelegate getViewNames, GetDefaultActionsDelegate getDefaultActions)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, String htmlFieldName, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData, ExecuteTemplateDelegate executeTemplate)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, String htmlFieldName, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateFor[TContainer,TValue](HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression, String templateName, String htmlFieldName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor[TModel,TValue](HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression)
   at ASP._Page_Views_Shared__ContactDetails_cshtml.Execute() in d:\websites\kpa.hrm.web\Views\Shared\_ContactDetails.cshtml:line 11
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
```

Comment: If you are iterating through any static or singleton collections, make sure they are thread safe

Comment: I did not find any place static or singleton collections are used, the views are just passed view models.

Comment: Then most likely you are adding or removing objects from the collection inside iteration. Keep in mind that you cannot modify the collection in foreach.